# Boolean Javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean

Javascript beginner here, I keep getting a wrong answer to this question:

"First, figure out if we have enough slices now. Use a comparison operator to figure out if there are enough. Assign the result to the enoughSlicesNow variable."

//Variables are below//

```
var cakes = 5;
var slicesPerCake = 6;
var attendees = 60;
var bakers = 3;
var cakeBakingTime = 1;
var hoursLeftUntilParty = 5;
```

This is what I tried but it will not accept:

```
(cakes * slicesPerCake)>= attendees 

var enoughSlicesNow = false
```

Comment: *"Assign the result to the enoughSlicesNow variable"* you are always assigning `false` to `enoughSlicesNow`, not the result of the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need:

```
var enoughSlicesNow = (cakes * slicesPerCake) >= attendees;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this using ternary operator

```
var cakes = 5;
var slicesPerCake = 6;
var attendees = 60;
var bakers = 3;
var cakeBakingTime = 1;
var hoursLeftUntilParty = 5;


 var enoughSlicesNow = (cakes * slicesPerCake) >= attendees ?true:false
alert(enoughSlicesNow)
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/awqj0s8h/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this...

```js
    var cakes = 5;
    var slicesPerCake = 6;
    var attendees = 60;
    var bakers = 3;
    var cakeBakingTime = 1;
    var hoursLeftUntilParty = 5;
    
    
     var enoughSlicesNow = (cakes * slicesPerCake)>= attendees;
     if(enoughSlicesNow ==true){
         alert('Enough');
       }
    else
    {
      alert('Not enough');
    }
```

Comment: `if(true == x)` should always be rewritten to `if(x)`, unless you are like using `===` and you know what you are doing

Comment: it is also possible to compare with `true`.